# Classifying $0; -3; -1$ for $\frac{z-3}{(z^2-9)z}e^{\frac{1}{1+z}}$ and is $3$ even a singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I want to find the singularities of 
$$\frac{z-3}{(z^2-9)z}e^{\frac{1}{1+z}}$$
Which at first sight are $-3, 3, 0, -1$.

The expression simplifies to 
$$\frac{1}{(z+3)z}e^{\frac{1}{1+z}}$$
leading me to my first question: Was $3$ a removable singularity? Or was it never a singularity to begin with?

Now, to classify $-3, 0, -1$, I wanted to use the Laurent series. I'm stuck. Expanding the exponential into a power series gives us the correct form for discussing the singularity at $-1$, i.e., $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!(z+1)^k}$. But how can we incorporate the fraction $\frac{1}{(z+3)z}$? I'm having similar problems when expanding the fraction into a power series. Basically, because the terms are **multiplied**, I don't know how to handle them.

Is there a clever way to work around even having to use the Laurent series? Or am I approaching calculating it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function is undefined at $3$, yes, it is a singularity. And, in fact, it is a removable singularity.

Since the limit $0$ is not a removable singularity of $\frac{z-3}{(z^2-9)z}e^{\frac1{1+z}}$, but the limit $\lim_{z\to0}z\times\frac{z-3}{(z^2-9)z}e^{\frac1{1+z}}$ exists (in $\mathbb C$), $0$ is a pole of $\frac{z-3}{(z^2-9)z}e^{\frac1{1+z}}$.

Finally, $-1$ is an essential singularity of $e^{\frac1{1+z}}$. Since $\frac{z-3}{(z^2-9)z}$ is analytic near $-1$, $-1$ is still an essential singularity of $\frac{z-3}{(z^2-9)z}e^{\frac1{1+z}}$.